# Make Prettier ignore JavaScript formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

In VSCode I have Prettier and ESLint installed. I have added the ESLint configuration to my user preferences settings, so the ESLint is the same on all projects.

I want Prettier to use ESLint as the formatter instead of its own, which I can do using:

```
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true
```

However, this does not actually use my ESLint configuration, which I wrote here:

```
"eslint.options": {
    "rules": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have enabled `editor.formatOnSave`, which should use the Prettier as the formatter (it might not, but I'm not sure).

How do I force ESLint to be the one and only formatter for JavaScript, but still have Prettier to format my CSS?

Alternatively: I think that when I have `editor.formatOnSave` enabled, it also formats my JavaScript. How do I disable that? It would appear the Prettier is only for JavaScript, TypeScript, and CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I figured it out:

```
"javascript.format.enable": false
```

This forces `editor.formatOnSave` to not format, but if I then do:

```
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true
```

It now formats my JavaScript by my ESLint configuration, while it uses the built-in HTML and CSS formatter for HTML and CSS. Exactly how I want it.